# Using getattr to run a function Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, format, exec, conditional-operator

I am trying to run the function `Order` which has 2 versions one function that is `client.LinearOrder.LinearOrder_new(side="Buy",symbol=tradingpair,order_type="Market",qty=1).result()` if the keyword "USDT" is present within `Pair` else it executes `client.Order.Order_new(side="Buy",symbol=tradingpair,order_type="Market",qty=1).result()`. When `Order_Execution` is split into two `Order` works as expected with the `getattr` function, I am trying to run it without splitting it, How would I modify the code below so that it works.

Working Code:

```
def Exec(Pair)
    Order_Execution = "LinearOrder" if "USDT" in tradingpair else "Order" 
    Order_Execution2 = "LinearOrder_new" if "USDT" in tradingpair else "Order_new"
    Order = getattr(getattr(client, Order_Execution), Order_Execution2)(side="Buy",symbol=tradingpair,order_type="Market",qty=1).result()
Exec("BTCUSD")
```

Unfunctional Code:

```
def Exec(Pair)
    Order_Execution = "LinearOrder.LinearOrder_new" if "USDT" in tradingpair else "Order.Order_new" 
    Order = getattr(client, Order_Execution)(side="Buy",symbol=tradingpair,order_type="Market",qty=1).result()
Exec("BTCUSD")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only split them. The second argument of:

```py
getattr(obj, attr)
```

is the name of an attribute of the object. Since a valid Python identifier cannot contain a dot, your unfunctional code simply fails.
Why don't you just simplify the problem ? Instead of using `getattr()`, you can:

```py
def Exec(Pair):
    if "USDT" in tradingpair:
        Order_Execution = client.LinearOrder.LinearOrder
    else:
        Order_Execution = client.Order.Order_new
    Order = Order_Execution(side="Buy",symbol=tradingpair,order_type="Market",qty=1).result()

Exec("BTCUSD")
```

*NOTE:* The parameter `Pair` of function `Exec` is unused.